# PHP : Sign Up Form animating

Tags: php, forms, registration

i want to do a sign up form who will instantly check the answer and if the form is valid, a green circle appear beside the form.

Comment: you might want to elaborate a bit..

Comment: It sounds like what he actually wants is to learn about ajax.

Comment: have a look at jQuery library.. you can use it to decorate ur form, do ajax and validations..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with Javascript and CSS:

Try something like this:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: i use it and work fine for me. Its my example [http://jsfiddle.net/HKty7/](http://jsfiddle.net/HKty7/)

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to check for the correct length and characters used, javascript will do. If you also want to perform checks like whether the username or email already exist, things get more complicated.
You could achieve that with AJAX http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

but be aware of webbots, because if you provide such functionality they can expose the existing users. Thats why login forms often answer "Username or password incorrect" although the user exists.